# lombok @Builder(toBuilder = true) compilation error when used on constructor of a sub class

Tags: java, lombok

My code is as followd

```
package test.lombok;

import lombok.*;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
public class SuperClass {

    private int foo;

    @Getter
    public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {

        private int bar;

        @Builder(toBuilder = true)
        private SubClass(int foo, int bar) {
            super(foo);
            this.bar = bar;
        }

    }
}
```

As showed above, I'm trying to use @Builder(toBuilder = true) on a sub class.

When *toBuilder* set to false, there is no problem at all.

But when I set *toBuilder = true*, I got an compilation error "Error:java: foo has private access in test.lombok.SuperClass".

I'm wondering why does this happen and how to fix this.

Comment: IMHO this is a Lombok bug. Assuming [I'm right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517971/581205), would you file [an issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues)?

Comment: Sure. I've posted an issue [#1488](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1488)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of how the `toBuilder` method is implemented in `SubClass`:

```
public SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder toBuilder() {
    return (new SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder()).foo(this.foo).bar(this.bar);
}
```

Instead of `this.foo` it should be `super.foo`, and the code would compile. Accessing `super.foo` is possible in this case because `SubClass` is an inner class of the `SuperClass`, otherwise, Java would disallow `super.foo` too.

If you want to see the code generated by lombok by for yourself, declare `foo` as public, then compile, then delombok (or decompile) and you will see code like this (then change the property to private to see where the error occurs):

```
import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;

public class SuperClass {
    public int foo;

    @ConstructorProperties({"foo"})
    protected SuperClass(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

    public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {
        private int bar;

        private SubClass(int foo, int bar) {
            super(foo);
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public static SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder builder() {
            return new SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder();
        }

        public SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder toBuilder() {
            return (new SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder()).foo(this.foo).bar(this.bar);
        }

        public int getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public static class SubClassBuilder {
            private int foo;
            private int bar;

            SubClassBuilder() {
            }

            public SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder foo(int foo) {
                this.foo = foo;
                return this;
            }

            public SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder bar(int bar) {
                this.bar = bar;
                return this;
            }

            public SuperClass.SubClass build() {
                return new SuperClass.SubClass(this.foo, this.bar);
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder(foo=" + this.foo + ", bar=" + this.bar + ")";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to @maaartinus for pointing me to `super.foo`, the answer is updated with that info.

Comment: Thank you, MondKin. Very detailed explanation! So I guess there is none way to make lombok generate toBuilder() of SubClass? Is it possible to call getFoo() instead of this.foo in toBuilder() ？

Comment: A solution is to declare `foo` as protected, that way you can access it from inside the SubClass. Otherwise, I'm not aware of a way to tell lombok to use the accessor methods instead.

Comment: @MondKin I guess, you missed a much nicer solution: Using `super.foo` as a field declared in the same source file *is* accessible. Obviously, this should be fixed in Lombok.

Comment: @maaartinus You are right, I hadn't noticed that replacing `this` by `super` at the lombok side would solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Lombok *tries to create* **toBuilder** method in **SubClass** when the attribute **toBuilder** is set to **true** in annotation **@Builder**. The method returns the **SubClassBuilder** class. Here is the what the **toBuilder** method would look like,

```
public SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder toBuilder() {
    return (new SuperClass.SubClass.SubClassBuilder())
                    .foo(this.foo).bar(this.bar);
}
```

As you notice, **toBuilder** method tries to access **foo** attribute directly and not by method **getFoo**. Since **foo** is private and belongs to the parent class, **SuperClass**, you get the following error:

**Error:java: foo has private access in test.lombok.SuperClass**

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT this is a Lombok bug. There are three ways, how to access `foo` and only one of them works:

- plain `foo` leads to "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field foo"
- `this.foo` as used by Lombok leads to "The field SuperClass.foo is not visible"
- `super.foo` works!

AFAIK *everything* declared in the same source file is accessible *somehow*, but finding the proper expression might be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Lombok 1.18.12, you can use the new, **experimental feature** [`@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder).

It supports `toBuilder` :

```java
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@ToString // For demonstration purposes only; only used in the main method.
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class SuperClass {

    private int foo;

    @Getter
    @ToString(callSuper = true) // For demonstration purposes only; only used in the main method.
    @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
    public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {

        private int bar;

        private SubClass(int foo, int bar) {
            super(foo);
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        SubClass sc = SubClass.builder()
                .foo(1)
                .bar(2)
                .build();
        System.out.println(sc);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
SuperClass.SubClass(super=SuperClass(foo=1), bar=2)
```